# Indexing into argv with literal vs variable

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, reference

I tracked down the source of my seg fault and am no looking for a solution to how to get around it.

Say that argv contains the data {"programName", "5"}

Now if I want to pass part of the argv data into another function I have two choices.

```
functionCall(argv[1]); //passes in the address of 5
```

This passes in the address of 5.

Now if I want to do this an `n` amount of times with a loop like:

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    functionCall(argv[i]);
}
```

The later way passes in the actual value of 5 not the address of 5 which then causes the atoi function to segfault. (It doesn't segfault on mingw but does with gcc).

How can I pass in the address of the value instead of the literal value?

Comment: Literal or variable doesn't matter. You have some other bug.

Comment: I have replaced the i in my code with a valid literal and I can see the difference.

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: *"The later way passes in the actual value of 5."* Not so, there is no difference between passing `argv[1]` and `argv[i]` when `i` is 1.

Comment: " 
I have replaced the i in my code with a valid literal and I can see the difference."  Post that.  I suspect you are confusing what a literal is in C.  Also post the declaration of `functionCall()`.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> functionCall(argv[1]);
> ```
>
> *This passes in the address of 5.*

No, it does not. There exist no *address* for an integer constant, an address is for an "object".

It passes a pointer (*as per the array decay when arrays are passed as function argument*) to the starting of a string `"5"` which is your program argument.

So to speak

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    functionCall(argv[i]);
}
```

appears legit as long as your function description and usage is OK. For example, for an `argc` value of `4`, the snippets

```
functionCall(argv[1]);
functionCall(argv[2]);
functionCall(argv[3]);
```

and

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
    functionCall(argv[i]);
}
```

are equivalent. So, the claim

> *Indexing into argv with literal vs variable* *[..produces different behaviour..]*

is not correct.

Comment: When I pass in a value instead of i I can see a different value being passed in even if the values are the same.

Comment: @frillybob How so? Need a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @chux No doubt, corrected and updated with a bit more info. :)